# Logical implication in type constraints (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, typeclass

How do I express the idea of a container that fulfills certain "transparency properties"? For example, consider a container type `v` such that `Show a` implies `Show (v a)`.

The use case is that I want to have a function where the callee decides what container to use, but the container is guaranteed to be well behaved with respect to many type-class constraints.

Here's a (non-working) example of what I have in mind:

```
mapUnknown :: (forall v. (Functor v, (forall n. Num n => Num (v n)) => v b -> a)) 
              -> [b] -> [a]
```

The idea is that you pass in a function, which must be able to handle any container type `v`. It is guaranteed that `v` is a `Functor` and that `Num b` implies `Num (v b)`. If the `b` you pass in isn't a `Num`, then that rule is ignored.

Is this possible?

Note:

The following does not work:

```
class Container c a where
  foo :: c a -> [a]

instance forall a c. (Container c a, Show a) => Show (c a) where
  show _ = "whatever"

f :: (Container c a, Show a) => c a -> String
f as =
  show as
```

This is because we can define an instance `Container V a` and also `Show (V a)`. GHC then can't figure out whether to use the `show` defined by `Container` or the show defined by `Show (V a)`. We don't want to define a new `show` function, we just want to assert that it exists once the type of the container is known.

Comment: Could you make a type class called Container, and then register all of your container data types as instances of that type class? Then instead of `mapUnknown` you could do `mapContainer`, and that function would be one that is required as part of the `Container` type class.

Comment: See edit -- it doesn't work.

Comment: What you are trying to do won't work, because `forall n. Num n => Num (v n)` is not a valid constraint. However, using the [constraints package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.4.1.3/docs/Data-Constraint.html), you can reify the constraint you want as a function of type `forall n . Num n :- Num (v n)`. The full type of your function could be `(forall n . Num n :- Num (v n)) -> (v b -> a) -> [b] -> [a]` - but I don't know what you actually want it to do. Your second example works if you enable `OverlappingInstances`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I understand correctly, you want to make a class, let's say `NumToNum`, such that from two instances `NumToNum v` and `Num n` the compiler would be able to deduce that there is an instance of `Num (v n)`. Here is how you can accomplish this.

The key thing here is to create a type, say, `NumI :: * -> *`, such that there won't be any values of type `NumI n`, unless `n` is of class `Num`. Strictly speaking, that's impossible, since any type in Haskell is inhabited (by `(_|_)`, at least). But, if you avoid explicitly marking implementation methods as `undefined` and delving into deep recursion, you'd be relatively safe with this:

```
data NumI n where NumI :: Num n => NumI n
```

So, if `n` is not of class `Num`, there is still the value `undefined` of type `Num n`, but not much else.

Of course, you need `GADTs` extension for that.

Now, the aforementioned class can be defined in this manner:

```
class NumToNum v where numToNum :: Num n => NumI (v n)
```

With that in hand, you could get your `Num (v n)` instance with pattern matching:

```
case (numToNum :: NumI (v n)) of NumI => do_something
```

Here `do_something` already knows about `Num (v n)` instance, thanks to the type signature of the constructor `NumI`.

Declaring instances of `NumToNum` class is easy, you just say

```
data V n = -- whatever
instance Num n => Num (V n) where -- some implementation
instance NumToNum V where numToNum = NumI
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not entirely getting it. If I have a function signature `(Applicative v, NumToNum v) => v String -> ()` would the compiler automatically realize that any `v Double`s I create are `Num`s? Or would I have to wrap everything in a pattern match to force it to realize it?

Comment: Would `:-` from `Data.Constraint` be useful here?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to use pattern matching everywhere. Yes, `:-` seems a way to go; I was just showing you how to do this by yourself.